# Find the nearest neighbor of coordinates in 2 separate matrices and the distance between the 2 in r

Tags: r, knn

I have 2 dataframes that are simply matrices of 2 dimensions (lat/long).  Both dataframes would look like the input below:

```
latitude  longitude
27.78833  -82.28197
27.79667  -82.29294
```

Let's call them "dfref" and "dfnew".  I would like to find the nearest point in `dfnew` for each point in `dfref` and the distance between the 2 points in meters.

The output would look like this:

```
dr.latitude  dr.longitude  dn.latitude  dn.longitude  dist
27.78833     -82.28197     27.54345     -82.33233     162.34
27.79667     -82.29294     27.56543     -82.12323     232.23
```

I have tried using the knn function in the class package and the Searchtrees package but my script only found the nearest points in the dfref matrix and I am not sure how to add the measurement.

```
knn1(train=cbind(dfref), test=cbind(dfnew), cl=seq_len(nrow(dfnew)))
```

Is there a function that does both efficiently and how can I get this into one script?

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on Geo math, but it seems that you can start with something like this:

```
dfref <- read.table(text = 
"latitude  longitude
27.78833  -82.28197
27.79667  -82.29294", header = T)
dtref <- data.table(dfref)

dfnew <- read.table(text = 
"latitude  longitude
27.54345     -82.33233", header = T)
dtnew <- data.table(dfnew)

# Make cartesian product of to tables.
dtref$fake <- 1
dtnew$fake <- 1
dtall <- merge(dtref, dtnew, by = "fake", allow.cartesian = T)

# Calculate distance.
library(geosphere)
dtall[, distance := distVincentyEllipsoid(c(longitude.x, latitude.x), c(longitude.y, latitude.y)), by = 1:nrow(dtall)]

# Print results.
dtall[, .(latitude.x, longitude.x, latitude.y, longitude.y, distance)]

#      latitude.x longitude.x latitude.y longitude.y distance
# 1:   27.78833   -82.28197   27.54345   -82.33233 27587.29
# 2:   27.79667   -82.29294   27.54345   -82.33233 28328.19
```

Comment: Thanks Bulat, however, I think I didn't explain my issue correctly.

I am trying to only find the distance of all points in dfref and only the nearest point in dfnew, not all points in dfref and all points in dfnew.  When trying to find all points, I ran into issues around memory allocation.

`1: In forderv(byval, sort = FALSE, retGrp = TRUE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8125Mb: see help(memory.size)`

Comment: don't you need to calculate distance to all points first to find nearest point?

Comment: A K Nearest Neighbors function can be used to find the nearest points so only the nearest point is returned prior to finding the actual distance.  I am attempting to use one in my original question, but did not quite understand the results.  Finding the distance for each point is a bit too intensive as I mentioned in my previous comment.  My dataframes are 10k and 15k rows each and I need to find an efficient way to deal with them.

Comment: Well, the only difference in using clustering knn will be the function which determines the distance. You can do first calculation using `d.proxy := x.diff^2 + y.diff^2`. Keep records with min distance proxy and calculate distance properly for those.

Comment: In terms of clustering, you can just split the map in sectors available in both datasets in say 100 squares `x.sector = cut(x, rep((x.max - x.min) / 10, 10)`. `sector = paste0(x.sector, '-',y.sector)`. for records that don't have a neighbor in the sector, you can extend the search. It will not guarantee the optimal result for each record though.